# Where can I get a 4.26µm wavelength light source with variable intensity?

Tags: electrical-engineering, waves, photonics

I want to conduct a small home experiment involving co2 particles detection.

In order to do that I need a light source at 4.26µm wavelength (it's absorbed by co2 molecules), preferably with configurable light intensity.

I checked various stores for LED sources and bandpass filters, but options that I found are too expensive for me (>300$). Is there a cheaper way I can get this? Makeshift options are also considered.

Comment: Sorry but expensive is pretty typical in this field.  If you had a way to detect and tweak, you could go makeshift via try and check but such devices are expensive too.  I suggest you pony up for that ~$500 band pass filter.

Comment: @Abel thank you